# Apache Virtualhost redirecting to first domain

Tags: redirect, apache

I have apache virtualhost configured properly.  Meaning when i go to www.myfirstsite.com it loads the welcome page i created for it, similarly when i go to www.mysecondsite.com it loads second welcome page.  This tells me everything is working properly.  The issue i have is when i transfer my magento site to www.mysecondsite.com it redirects to www.myfirstsite.com  What could be going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

In Most cases, the cause is database configuration values.

Go to `core_config_data` table and change the path  www.myfirstsite.com to www.mysecondsite.com

```
select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%'
```

Remove the cache and try.

**Good to have a database backup before doing any modification.**

Hope this helps.

Comment: i changed the baseurl as you suggested and it didn't work.  Also i have file permissions for folders set to 755 and for files 777.  So everything should be accessible, but it still redirects to www.myfirtsite.com

Comment: Search the string "www.myfirstsite.com" in database as well as in your instance. Assume there is hot coding some-wear.

Comment: Check if there is any redirect in .htaccess file and ask host provider for IP redirects.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the replies.  This is what ended up working for me.

Step 1- Go to mysql database

Step 2- Go to core_config_data

Step 3- Search for unsecure and secure base url

Step 4- Change it to the new website address, in my case www.mysecondsite.com

Step 5- Reboot apache, I am using Centos 7.  So in your SSH session type "reboot"

Step 6- Check to see if the changes worked, in my case when i go to www.mysecondsite.com it loads the correct page.

Hope this helps other people.  Thanks.